# Configuring SVN repository in Amazon EC2 Ubuntu AMI

Tags: svn, ubuntu

I've installed a subversion server in my Ubuntu AMI. I want to access it via svn+ssh with different users (not 'ubuntu' default user). So, I can create different user accounts with 'useradd', but I'm worried about security.

I've used the 'ubuntu' user for other dev tasks, and I only need different users for subversion. Is 'useradd' the safer way? In other words: What's the safer method to provide different users commit access to my subversion repository in an Ubuntu EC2 AMI?

Many thanks in advance, and best regards

Comment: How do you serve subversion? Apache and Webdav or svnserve? Also voting to migrate to serverfault

Comment: svnserve, but I could use Apache too. My decision. Should I do something to migrate the question to serverfault?

Comment: This question might help: http://serverfault.com/q/148418/15186

Comment: Yes, I think this is going to be useful. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SVN book [section on svnserve](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html) teaches how to setup svn+ssh authentication

Comment: Yes, I read it. I could configure it without creating system users. Apache and mod_dav did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked. Don't hesitate to post the solution as an answer to your question!

Comment: Finally, I followed this instructions http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/install-subversion-with-web-access-on-ubuntu/ and it worked well.